# Measuring the randomness in random numbers

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability

I'm looking to write a program to investigate a few random number algorithms.  Basically I am looking to see if the spread of numbers is indeed randomly distributed enough.  What kind of statistical analysis would I be looking to do?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php

Comment: This is good...very good.  Anything a bit lighter and just for fun?  I'm more interested in the theory than the actual results.

Comment: @DanDan: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: Earlier MO post gives some examples of tests http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37518/why-do-statistical-randomness-tests-seem-so-ad-hoc

Comment: I don't know whether Knuth, The Art Of Computer Programming, is light, but it is fun, and Volume 2, Seminumerical Algorithms, goes into the theory of randomness in some detail. 